# Phonegap - Cross-domain call on iOS app

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm creating iOS app that needs to send data to a spreadsheet for google.
Sending data only works from a browser, but does not work when compiled.

Following various indications found in stackoverflow I modified the file confing.xml present in cordova, adding:

```
...<access origin="google*" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="mydomain*" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>...
```

Following the changes made to the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
$.support.cors = true;
...

$.ajax({
        url: urlGdoc+params,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType : "jsonp json",
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
           },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
           }
    });
```

Thank you!